# Record equality in coq

Tags: coq

For example I have this sample record:

```
Record Sample := {
  SA :> nat ; 
  SB :> Z ; 
  SCond : Z.abs_nat SB <> SA
}.
```

When I want to proof this Lemma :

```
Lemma Sample_eq : forall a b : Sample , a = b <-> SA a = SA b /\ SB a = SB b.
```

I see this :

```
1 subgoal
______________________________________(1/1)
forall a b : Sample, a = b <-> a = b /\ a = b
```

Question 1 : How to force Coq to show SA a instead of a?

Question 2 : How to proof this Lemma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1**

Coq prints `SA` because you declared it as a coercion.  You can prevent this by adding the option `Set Printing Coercions.` to your file.  As far as I know, there is no way of just making Coq print *only* `SA` but not other coercions such as `SB`. You can, however, replace the `:>` by `:` to prevent `SA` from being declared as a coercion.

**Question 2**

Your lemma cannot be proved without assuming extra axioms into Coq's theory.  The problem is that you need to show that two proofs of `Z.abs_nat SB <> SA` are equal in order to show that two records of type `Sample` are equal, and there is nothing  in Coq's theory that can help you with that. You have two options:

1. Use the axiom of proof irrelevance, which says `forall (P : Prop) (p1 p2 : P), p1 = p2`. For example:

   ```
   Require Import Coq.ZArith.ZArith.
   Require Import Coq.Logic.ProofIrrelevance.

   Record Sample := {
     SA : nat;
     SB : Z;
     SCond : Z.abs_nat SB <> SA
   }.

   Lemma Sample_eq a b : SA a = SA b -> SB a = SB b -> a = b.
   Proof.
     destruct a as [x1 y1 p1], b as [x2 y2 p2].
     simpl.
     intros e1 e2.
     revert p1 p2.
     rewrite <- e1, <- e2.
     intros p1 p2.
     now rewrite (proof_irrelevance _ p1 p2).
   Qed.
   ```

   (Note the calls to `revert`: they are needed to prevent dependent type errors when rewriting with `e1` and `e2`.)
2. Replace inequality with a proposition for which proof irrelevance is valid without extra axioms.  A typical solution is to use a boolean version of the proposition. The `DecidableEqDepSet` module shows that the proofs of equality for a type that has decidable equality, such as the booleans, satisfies proof irrelevance.

   ```
   Require Import Coq.ZArith.ZArith.
   Require Import Coq.Logic.ProofIrrelevance.
   Require Import Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.

   Module BoolDecidableSet <: DecidableSet.

   Definition U := bool.
   Definition eq_dec := Bool.bool_dec.

   End BoolDecidableSet.

   Module BoolDecidableEqDepSet := DecidableEqDepSet BoolDecidableSet.

   Record Sample := {
     SA : nat;
     SB : Z;
     SCond : Nat.eqb (Z.abs_nat SB) SA = false
   }.

   Lemma Sample_eq a b : SA a = SA b -> SB a = SB b -> a = b.
   Proof.
     destruct a as [x1 y1 p1], b as [x2 y2 p2].
     simpl.
     intros e1 e2.
     revert p1 p2.
     rewrite <- e1, <- e2.
     intros p1 p2.
     now rewrite (BoolDecidableEqDepSet.UIP _ _ p1 p2).
   Qed.
   ```